# How to build the query dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am creating a query like this:

```
v_sql:=' SELECT abc FROM '||v_table||' 
         WHERE area IN ('''||v_area||''') 
           AND (
                ('''||p_supp_nbr||''' IS NULL) 
                OR 
                supplr_vn IN ('''||p_supp_nbr||''')
               )
```

Now when the `p_supp_nbr` is `NULL` then its not taking.

I get like this:

`((''IS NULL) OR (supplr_vn =''))`

Its checking space in the table

but i want `((NULL IS  NULL) OR (supplr_vn =NULL))` so that condition bcomes ineffective

Comment: There's no need to check whether or not `null is null`.

Comment: I will need to check bcos it is an optional parameter.Currently its checking space in the table

Comment: No, you don't understand. There's no need to include `null is null` as a part of any `where` clause. Simply don't include that part of the `where` clause if `p_supp_nbr is null`.

Comment: If I dont include when the user dont enter anything in the parameter i need to neglect the condition. If I check supplr_Vvn=NULL then its wrong.SO that condition is required

Comment: 0_0 Ummm...you don't ever want to check whether anything *equals* `null`. Null isn't a value. Just alter the `where` clause depending on which (if any) of your parameters happen to be `null`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do that!  You risk SQL Injection issues.  Use bind variables:

```
v_sql:= 'SELECT abc FROM '||v_table||
        ' WHERE area = :v_area
           AND (
                :p_supp_nbr IS NULL
                OR 
                supplr_vn = :p_supp_nbr
               )
```

Of course since you know at the point of generating the dynamic SQL whether the value is null you could instead do this:

```
v_sql:= 'SELECT abc FROM '||v_table||' 
         WHERE area = :v_area';
IF p_supp_nbr IS NULL THEN
    v_sql := v_sql || ' AND :p_supp_nbr IS NULL';
ELSE
    v_sql := v_sql || ' AND supplr_vn = :p_supp_nbr';
END IF;
```

Either way you can then bind the values at runtime like this:

```
OPEN my_refcursor FOR v_sql USING v_area, p_supp_nbr;
```

Comment: I like the second one best! But isn't the first part of the `if` statement superfluous? Wouldn't this work: `IF p_supp_nbr IS NOT NULL THEN v_sql := v_sql || ' AND supplr_vn = :p_supp_nbr'; END IF;`

Comment: @glh I should have explained in my answer: yes it is logically superfluous, but Native Dynamic SQL only works when the number of bind variables is fixed, so we need to reference :p_supp_nbr in the query whether we use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
v_sql:=' SELECT abc FROM '||v_table||'
WHERE area IN ('''||v_area||''') 
  AND (('''||p_supp_nbr||''' IS NULL) 
  OR supplr_vn IN ('''||NVL(p_supp_nbr, 'NULL')||'''))
```

Comment: In the above Query when p_supp_nbr IS NULL then its checking ' ' IS NULL.so space is not NULL right

Answer (score 0):

General Oracle example:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql1        VARCHAR2(200);
  v_sql2        VARCHAR2(200);
  v_tab_name    VARCHAR2(200):= 'scott.emp';
  v_listCol     VARCHAR2(200):= 'job';
  v_list        VARCHAR2(200):= '''MANAGER'', ''CLERK''';
 --
  v_colName     VARCHAR2(200):= 'comm';
  v_comm        NUMBER:= 1400;
BEGIN
  v_sql1:= 'SELECT * FROM '|| v_tab_name ||' WHERE '||v_listCol ||' IN (:v)';
  v_sql2:= 'SELECT * FROM '|| v_tab_name ||' WHERE ('||v_colName ||' = :v OR '||v_colName ||' IS NULL)';
 --
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql1 USING v_list;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql1);
 --
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 USING v_comm;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql2);
END;
/
```